# Java stream collect toConcurrentHashMap error

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following stream which takes each contact and should create a ConcurrentHashMap with the id of each contact as the key and an empty Optional as the value. I tried to use the finisher to produce the Map in the correct form because without it there was a type mismatch as the Optional was not typed. With the following code i get '(' or '[' expected at the second to last bracket.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap = 
contacts.stream().collect(
    Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
            Contact::getCid, s -> Optional.empty()
        ),
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> 
     )
 );
```

I have also tried using ConcurrentHashMap:: with Integer , Optional type BlockingQueue type Packet as an alternative finisher which also didn't work. What could be the problem with my stream?

Thanks

Comment: What is contacts? You can add the type when you call a static method too.`Optional.<BlockingQueue<Packet>>empty();` https://ideone.com/lr8jjC

Comment: Hi, Contacts is just an object I made with an integer id field called cid. Your suggestion did the trick, thank you. However I had to use the finisher when surely there would be no need for it given the type would be correct anyway. This is what I updated it to, is there a version without the finaliser?:                    `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap = contacts.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Contact::getCid, s -> Optional.<BlockingQueue<Packet>>empty()), ConcurrentHashMap::new)); `

Comment: You have new ConcurrentHashMap<...> but you don't have the () for it. You don't need the 'and then bits though'.

Comment: Be careful the terms can be a bit misleading. Finalisers are an api you probably should avoid, the collect and then uses a 'finisher'. If you want to use the finisher, then you can use: ConcurrentHashMap::new as a constructor reference.

Comment: The reason you need a finisher is because you want a `ConcurrentHashMap` then you either need to use a finisher, or you need to use the four argument `toMap` function. The way you have it written, toConcurrentMap returns a ConcurrentMap, the implementation details are hidden.

Comment: You don't really need to go round about that, you can use the default implementation of the collector for `ConcurrentMap`  such as `ConcurrentMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap = contacts.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Contact::getCid, c -> Optional.empty()));`

Comment: Hi @Naman your code is more concise, thank you. But how is it specified that you wish for a ConcurrentHashMap without the explicit finisher? As your code returns a ConcurrentMap rather than the required ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: @nrmad I have moved the explanation to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62611919/1746118), hope that would help both simplify and clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to go round about that, you can use the in-built implementation of the collector for this

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap = contacts.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Contact::getCid, s -> Optional.empty()));
```

Note, `ConcurrentMap` is an `interface` and `ConcurrentHashMap` is one of its implementations. The default `Collectors.toConcurrentMap` implementation chooses `ConcurrentHashMap::new` as the `supplier` for the result container in the above operation.

Or the other overload of the `Collectors.toConcurrentMap` could be used to explicitly cast the result into `ConcurrentHashMap`, such as:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Optional<BlockingQueue<Packet>>> channelMap = contacts.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(Contact::getCid, s -> Optional.empty(),
                (a, b) -> a, ConcurrentHashMap::new));
```